# Join multiple tables - Flutter - Firebase

Tags: sql, firebase, nosql, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have three collections: Cars, Makes, Models. A car has a make, model and price. The reason why I have separate collections is because I would like to display the makes on their own and models on their own eventually.

[image]

I would like to display each car with its make, model and price.

In SQL I can join the tables and compare by Id's. I'm not sure how I can replicate a join in nosql.

Comment: You can put all of that data into one collection and still display makes, models and cars.

Answer (score 1):

in NoSQL, you can't do it in one query. you have to divided to multiple queries :

first query : to get the data from the main table (in your case: **Cars** module)

second query: to get the data from the joined tables (  **Makes, Models** )

for example using JavaScript

```
    carTable.on('value', function (snapshot) {
        var makeID = snapshot.val().makeID; 
        makesTable.child('makes').child(makeID).once('value', function(mediaSnap) {
            console.log(makeID + ":" + mediaSnap.val());
        });

         var modelsID = snapshot.val(). modelsID; 
        modelsTable.child('models').child(modelsID).once('value', function(mediaSnap) {
            console.log(modelsID + ":" + mediaSnap.val());
        });


    });
```

so, you have to join the tables in 2 steps.